# How to write a formula in excel to find the lowest stage of progress/ mastery level completed by all the candidates given?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a worksheet in which there are x number of candidates in each group. I want to to check the lowest mastery level that has been completed by all the candidates in each group. There will obviously be candidates who have already surpassed the level but the lowest level that is applicable to all the members of the group.I hope to then add a multiplying constant based on the level achieved by all the members of the group. The levels of interest are as follows:

```
 "Participation in activity"
 "Mastery Level 1"
 "Mastery Level 2"
 "Mastery Level 3"
  etc.
```

There will also be an "Absent" level which I would like to exclude from the analysis. I tried to work this out using various forms of the IF function but was unable to achieve any progress with it. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

```
 "Group 1"
 **Name**      **Mastery Level**    **Points**
 "Person A"    "Mastery Level 2"       "2"
 "Person B"    "Absent"                "0"
 "Person C"    "Mastery Level 1"       "1"
 "Person D"    "Mastery Level 2"       "2"
 "Person E"    "Mastery Level 3"       "3"
                    **SUBTOTAL**       "8"
  _Multiplier_ "Mastery Level 1"       "x2"
                       **TOTAL**       "16"  

 "Group 2"
 **Name**      **Mastery Level**    **Points**
 "Person F"    "Mastery Level 2"       "2"
 "Person G"    "Absent"                "0"
 "Person H"    "Mastery Level 2"       "2"
 "Person I"    "Mastery Level 2"       "2"
 "Person J"    "Mastery Level 3"       "3"
                    **SUBTOTAL**       "9"
  _Multiplier_ "Mastery Level 2"       "x3"
                       **TOTAL**       "27"
```

Comment: Hi, we will be much better able to help if we don't have to make the data up ourselves. Can you provide some sample data, and show us what the expected output looks like?

Comment: You can probably do this with a Pivot Table. If you want help from the members, please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See answer below. Is it clear enough and does this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your workbook, you will have somehow to make a correspondance table from your qualitative criteria to (thus newly made) quantitative ones. *E.g.*

```
**qualit. Level**    **quant. Level** 
"Mastery Level 1"    1
"Mastery Level 2"    2
"Mastery Level 3"    3
"Absent"             =""
```

Say the above table is at `A1:C5`in the worksheet you want. Then, in the same worksheet, say that your group1's table is at `D1:F6`. With no vba and reporting group1's table for the sake of clarity, I would do something like

```
**Name**    **Mastery Level**    **Points**
"Person A"  "Mastery Level 2"    =VLOOKUP($E2,$A$2:$B$5,2,False)
"Person B"  "Absent"             =VLOOKUP($E3,$A$2:$B$5,2,False)
"Person C"  "Mastery Level 1"    =VLOOKUP($E4,$A$2:$B$5,2,False)
"Person D"  "Mastery Level 2"    =VLOOKUP($E5,$A$2:$B$5,2,False)
"Person E"  "Mastery Level 3"    =VLOOKUP($E6,$A$2:$B$5,2,False)
             **SUBTOTAL**        =SUM(F2:F6)
             **Min mast. Lev.**  =MIN(F2:F6)
             **TOTAL**           =F7*COUNTIF(F2:F6,F8)
```

Where `VLOOKUP` means, *e.g.* the one at cell `F2`,

> In table `$A$2:$B$5`, search for the value in cell `E2`, return the 2nd adjacent column and do it with no approximation

Comment: Thanks a million! This looks striaghtforward enough to implement straight off. This is perfect.